# Is it possible to have a record array as record field?

Tags: arrays, field, record

I'd like to know if it is possible using an array of Trecord as record field?

Eg.

```
Type

TRunway = record;
  ID : String;
  QFU: String;
  Length: String;
  ....
end;

TAirport = record;
  ICAO: String;
  Name: String;
  ....
  Runways: Array<TRunway>;
end;
```

If so, as different airport have different number of runway, how to set the length of Trunway array field?

Answer (score 0):

Answer found by myself.

Yes Tarray can be a record fiels.
Length is set as for a dynamic array.

Best regards
Pierre